# How to update PersistentState when LinearState is updated

Tags: corda

QueryableState.generateMappedObject define data to be inserted when State is created. However, I want to update Table defined by PersistentState when LinearState is Changed. How to keep data consistent between PersistentState Table data and ContractState vault data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can actually do this as far as I know.

I'd be curious about the use case as I've never heard of a situation where someone wanted to have a single state be both changing, *and unchanging*.

Take a look at this question on the distinctions between the states as that may also be helpful for you.

- [Corda - Persistence State V/S Linear State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63636137/corda-persistence-state-v-s-linear-state)